# Copy User Description and add new User with the same Description

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I have this table UserInfo

```
UserInfo
-------------------------------------
UserID FirstName,LastName, Description
--------------------------------------
1   Kevin    Love       Forward
2   Stephen  Curry      Guard
```

1. I want to copy `UserID 2 Description` on the same table but with new User with new UserID
2. I have two pages for these:

   - UserList page - Display all records in UserInfo and had an option
     `Copy` that          will copy `Description` on selected User and will
     redirect to my second page 'CopyInfo'.
   - CopyInfo page - will display and ask User only for new `Firstname, LastName` and the selected
     `UserID 2` `Description`.

Output:

```
UserInfo
-------------------------------------
UserID FirstName,LastName, Description
--------------------------------------
1   Kevin    Love       Forward
2   Stephen  Curry      Guard
3.  Steve    Kerr       Guard
```

please help. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure why this question is tagged asp-classic as it is purely SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `UserID is an IDENTITY` and you are using `SQL2005 and later`, you can use below query:

```
with ct as (
  select [Description] from UserInfo 
  where UserID = 2
)
insert into UserInfo (FirstName, Lastname, Description)
values ('Steve', 'Kerr', ct.Description)
```

If `UserID is not IDENTITY`, you need to have a value for it in your `INSERT` statement

Comment: Will try to implement it on my CopyInfo page.